# How to show collection view 3 columns in 1 row with RxSwift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, rx-swift

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import RxSwift
import RxCocoa
import RxOptional

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        let items = Observable.just(
            (0..<20).map{ "Test \($0)" }
        )

        items.asObservable().bindTo(self.collectionView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: CustomCollectionViewCell.reuseIdentifier, cellType: CustomCollectionViewCell.self)) { row, data, cell in
            cell.data = data
            }.addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
    }
}
```

[image]

So how to show 3 columns in 1 row.

I can't find any tutorial about collection view with RxSwift.

Comment: Try to increase width of CollectionViewCell

Comment: Hi @guru, do you know how to do it in code?

Comment: func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        
        
        return CGSize(width: yourWidth  , height: yourHeight )
        
    }

Comment: No, in RxSwift way...

Comment: Have you checked RxCollectionViewDataSourceType

Comment: Not yet, I will check it. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Something like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    ....

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

            ...

        items.asObservable().bindTo(self.collectionView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: CustomCollectionViewCell.reuseIdentifier, cellType: CustomCollectionViewCell.self)) { row, data, cell in
            cell.data = data
        }.addDisposableTo(disposeBag)

        // add this line you can provide the cell size from delegate method
        collectionView.rx.setDelegate(self).addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let width = collectionView.bounds.width
        let cellWidth = (width - 30) / 3 // compute your cell width
        return CGSize(width: cellWidth, height: cellWidth / 0.6)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @beethOven, `collectionView.rx.setDelegate(self).addDisposableTo(disposeBag)` cannot pass `self` here.

Comment: I need to add `class SecondViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`, it works. Thanks

Comment: You are welcome! i forgot to added `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`.

Answer (score 6):

Another alternative:

```
let flowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
let size = (collectionView.frame.size.width - CGFloat(30)) / CGFloat(3)
flowLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: size, height: size)
collectionView.setCollectionViewLayout(flowLayout, animated: true)
```